# What linux kernel code creates /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX?

Tags: linux, kernel, sysfs, microblaze

I am developing a cpufreq driver (as a loadable kernel module) for the microblaze architecture. I have some FPGA logic that is able to scale the on-system clock and it works quite well.  I have followed the information in `Documentation/cpu-freq/cpu-drivers.txt` and looked at the model in the blackfin cpufreq driver.

I have also made the necessary changes to `arch/microblaze/Kconfig` in order to have the cpufreq options built into the kernel (not modules).

When I first loaded the driver, `cpufreq_register_driver()` was returning -ENODEV, which implied that it couldn't find a CPU.  I set the driver flag to CPUFREQ_STICKY and was able to insert the module.

However, at this point I realized that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0` isn't present (although `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq` is there).  So, why is that?  What part of the kernel code is responsible for creating that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered where the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX` sysfs entry was created by looking at the `cpufreq_cpu_callback()` in `drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c`.  This has a call to `get_cpu_sysdev()`, which I assumed was the element that I was looking for.

This call is defined in `drivers/base/cpu.c`, where I also noticed the code that puts together the cpu specific sysdev entry; `register_cpu()`.  For most architectures, this is in `arch/${ARCH}/kernel/setup.c`, and I used the blackfin code as an example.

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct cpu, cpu_data);
static int __init topology_init(void)
{
    unsigned int cpu;
    for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) {
        register_cpu(&per_cpu(cpu_data, cpu), cpu);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After adding this code to `arch/microblaze/kernel/setup.c`, I now have the directory I need and I'm able to make use of the different governors available to talk to my cpufreq driver.  Now I just have to make `sleep 1` take 1 second at 1/3 the clock rate instead of 3 seconds!